# Big Integer - What is this code doing?

Tags: java, chord

I understand this questions is strange, not my usual style. I am currently doing a project using a chord implementation in peersim. The code below shows a big integer and some operation being carried out on it. My `chordId` is a hash of an object, why would you want to use `add()`? what purpose does this serve?

```
BigInteger base;
if (j == 0)
    base = BigInteger.ONE;
else {
    base = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
    for (int exp = 1; exp < j; exp++) {
        base = base.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
    }
}
BigInteger pot = cp.chordId.add(base);
```

Prior to his the chord Id was just a random integer of the idlength which was 128 bit.

My question therefore is what is the piece of code above `add()` used for???

**[EDIT]**

To put it into a bit of perspective to make this question clearer:

```
cp.fingerTable[j] = findId(pot, 0, Network.size() - 1);
```

is called which attempts to find the Id of Pot however it is always returning in error because the chordId created in this method does not exist. I am unsure of what to replace pot with or whether to take it out completely.

**[EDIT2]**

`findId` looks like this (this is not my code hence my confusion :))

```
public Node findId(BigInteger id, int nodeOne, int nodeTwo) {
    if (nodeOne >= (nodeTwo - 1))
        return Network.get(nodeOne);
    int middle = (nodeOne + nodeTwo) / 2;
    if (((middle) >= Network.size() - 1))
        System.out.print("ERROR: Middle is bigger than Network.size");
    if (((middle) <= 0))
        return Network.get(0);
    try {
        BigInteger newId = ((ChordProtocol) ((Node) Network.get(middle))
                .getProtocol(pid)).chordId;
        BigInteger lowId;
        if (middle > 0)
            lowId = ((ChordProtocol) ((Node) Network.get(middle - 1))
                    .getProtocol(pid)).chordId;
        else
            lowId = newId;
        BigInteger highId = ((ChordProtocol) ((Node) Network
                .get(middle + 1)).getProtocol(pid)).chordId;
        if (id.compareTo(newId) == 0
                || ((id.compareTo(newId) == 1) && (id.compareTo(highId) == -1))) {
            return Network.get(middle);
        }
        if ((id.compareTo(newId) == -1) && (id.compareTo(lowId) == 1)) {
            if (middle > 0)
                return Network.get(middle - 1);
            else
                return Network.get(0);
        }
        if (id.compareTo(newId) == -1) {
            return findId(id, nodeOne, middle);
        } else if (id.compareTo(newId) == 1) {
            return findId(id, middle, nodeTwo);
        }
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `findId()` look like?

Answer (score 5):

This is what the code would look like if `base` were an int instead of a `BigInteger`:

```
int base;
if (j == 0)
    base = 1;
else {
    base = 2;
    for (int exp = 1; exp < j; exp++) {
        base = base * 2;
    }
}
int pot = cp.chordId + base;
```

Actually that whole code snippet could be replaced with:

```
BigInteger base = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(j);
BigInteger pot = cp.chordId.add(base);
```

Which means it's equivalent to:

```
int base = (int) Math.pow(2, j);
int pot = cp.chordId + base;
```

It basically adds
 2<sup>j</sup> to `cp.chordId`

Comment: it has to be a biginteger for the purpose of the application unfortunately, but its always good to see how to do something differently.

Comment: @RossAlexander Sure. But `BigInteger` does have a `.pow()` method

Comment: @RossAlexander The code will still be functionally the same; so if it was giving you an error before, that won't change. You'll have to hunt down why it's not returning what it's supposed to. From the looks of the code you just posted, that would be way too much for a Stack Overflow question. Try to narrow down the problem and ask a new question if you have to.

Comment: i was not having problems before when it was using random big integers could this make a difference? thanks for all your help by the way I wasnt expecting a response at all really with this!!

Comment: @RossAlexander What do you mean by "random big integers"?

Comment: cp.chordId = hash.HashFunc((objectId).getBytes("UTF-8")); is used at the moment however it used to be simply cp.chordId = new BigInteger(idLength, CommonState.r) << commonstate.r gives a random big int

Comment: @RossAlexander But the hash function is deterministic, isn't it? (ie: it generates the same hash given the same input.) So it's not actually random.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249334/will-this-give-a-128-bit-hash I posted this (this is my hash code if you are interested)

Answer (score 1):

It is computing 2 ** j and then adding it to cp.chordId.
The if is for the special case where s ** 0 = 1 which is not really needed.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the piece of code above add() used for?

`cp.chordId` is of type `BigInteger`, and [`add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#add%28java.math.BigInteger%29) is used to add the object `cp.chordId` to the passed object `base` and returns a new `BigInteger` that has the value of adding both `BigInteger`'s: `cp.chordId` and `base`.

Answer (score 1):

```
cp.chordId.add(base);
```

With that it looks like it's trying to give the `cp.chordId` a base-value depending on the value of `j`.

So, if `j` is 0 the base-value for `chordid` will be `BigInteger.ONE` else the base for `chorid` will be `"2 ^ j"` (i.e. 2<sup>j</sup>).